# How to add a column that contains the next date column with SQL oracle developper

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to add a column to my table that contains the next Birthdate (ordered by Birthdate)

This is my actuale table:

| ID | Birthdate |
| --- | --- |
| Personne1 | 19/11/90 19:14:52,182000000 |
| Personne1 | 19/11/90 20:00:52,170000000 |
| Personne1 | 19/11/90 21:00:00,190000000 |

And I'm looking for this table

| ID | Birthdate | nextdate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Personne1 | 19/11/94 90:14:52,182000000 | 90/11/94 20:00:52,170000000 |
| Personne1 | 19/11/94 90:00:52,170000000 | 90/11/94 21:00:00,190000000 |
| Personne1 | 19/11/94 90:00:00,190000000 | N/A |

Is there any function like 'NEXT(Birthdate)' ? in order to calculate the difference in min:ss between the Birthdate column and the next_Birthday column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be `LEAD` analytic function.

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (id, birthdate) as
  2    (select 'personne1', to_timestamp('19.11.1990 19:14:52,182000000', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss,ff9') from dual union all
  3     select 'personne1', to_timestamp('19.11.1990 20:00:52,170000000', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss,ff9') from dual union all
  4     select 'personne1', to_timestamp('19.11.1990 21:14:00,190000000', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss,ff9') from dual
  5    ),
```

As you want to calculate *something* based on those values, use `extract` function which works well on timestamps (which is what you, apparently, have):

```
  6  temp as
  7    (select id,
  8       birthdate,
  9       lead(birthdate) over (partition by id order by birthdate) nextdate
 10     from test
 11    )
 12  select id, birthdate, nextdate,
 13    extract(minute from (nextdate - birthdate)) mins,
 14    extract(second from (nextdate - birthdate)) secs
 15  from temp;

ID        BIRTHDATE                      NEXTDATE                             MINS       SECS
--------- ------------------------------ ------------------------------ ---------- ----------
personne1 19.11.90 19:14:52,182000000    19.11.90 20:00:52,170000000            45     59,988
personne1 19.11.90 20:00:52,170000000    19.11.90 21:14:00,190000000            13       8,02
personne1 19.11.90 21:14:00,190000000

SQL>
```